# facebook login ios 8 safari Please close this tab to continue to

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use the facebook API to authenticate on my website

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
  FB.init({
    appId: 'XXXXXX',
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true
  });
};

(function (doc) {
  var js;
  var id = 'facebook-jssdk';
  var ref = doc.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  if (doc.getElementById(id)) {
    return;
  }
  js = doc.createElement('script');
  js.id = id;
  js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js";
  ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));

function Login() {
  FB.login(function (response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
      FB.api('/me', function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "xxxxx&format=json",
        data: {email:response.email, fb_id:response.id, name:response.first_name, surname:response.last_name},
        success: function(data){

          window.location = data.url;

        }
        });

      });
    } else {
      alert("Login attempt failed!");
    }
  }, { scope: 'email' });
}
```

With ios 7 after authentication redirects correctly to the site.

With ios 8 asks me "**Please close this tab to continue to ...**"

How can I fix this?